# ServiceStack.Redis reading large files from Redis server

Tags: windows, redis, servicestack, windows-server-2003, socketexception

I was testing the ServiceStack Redis client and i got an error related to the size of the package in Windows Server 2003 R2.

For files smaller than 30MB works fine, but for files bigger than 32-33MB it started to send errors. And it only happened in Windows Server 2003 R2, I tested in Windows 7 and Windows 2008 R2 successfully.

The code:

```cs
String text = File.ReadAllText("file.xml");
String key = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();            
if (redisClient.Add(key, text, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(300)))
    String Result = redisClient.Get<object>(key) as String;
```

The error:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
```

Does anyone know if it is because an OS restriction or it is a problem with the ServiceStack client for Redis.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem.  While I did see solutions online related to changing things like the TCP window size/etc., I simply gzipped everything.  This won't work in all cases (especially if the content is already compressed!), but if compression is an option I would try that.